# Is there a way to represent an enum class in Visio 2007?

Tags: class, enums, uml, diagram, visio

I am designing a Class Diagram (static structure) and would like to include some Enum classes. However I cannot seem to find a suitable way to represent this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Create a datatype, go to Properties, and apply the stereotype `enumeration` to it.

Answer (score 1):

1. choose UML Static Structures> DataType.
2. Properties> 'Stereotype' to 'Enumeration'
3. Add Enum values (LHS panel has 'Enumeration' listed for this. This is enabled by Step-2

Refer Image:
[image]